# Easing my organization into using BPMN

Tags: bpmn

I want to introduce my shop to BPMN. I know BPMN is very complicated and there are a lot of symbols to learn.  What are the 20% of the symbols that are used 80% of the time?

The industry I work in is traditional business. Not a lot of real time processing except timers to kick off backups. Data flow to/from our company to others. Client-server web-based systems...

Answer (score 0):

Use this [BPMN Poster](http://www.bpmb.de/index.php/BPMNPoster) as a reference. It contains most (if not all) of elements used in BPMN 2.0 and can be printed on a single A4 sheet (well A3 is a bit easier to read). And is available for free in many languages. Just send it to your co-workers.

While using BPMN focus mainly on Collaboration Diagram (except two frames in the middle of the top of diagram everything else from the poster applies).